# How can I scrape data from url using cheerio in node.js

Tags: node.js, puppeteer, cheerio

Please help me how I can **scrape** data from url using cheerio in node.js

Here is my current code.

```
const scraperObject = {
    url: 'https://www.example.com',
    async scraper(browser){
        let page = await browser.newPage();
        console.log(`Navigating to ${this.url}...`);
        await page.goto(this.url);
        await page.waitForSelector('.product-container');
        let urls = await page.$$eval('.JIIxO > ._1OUGS', links => {
            links = links.map(el => el.querySelector('._1OUGS > ._9tla3').href)
            return links;
        });
        console.log(urls);
    }
}
```

I need to **scrape** it using cheerio.
Thanks

Comment: I can tell from the selectors this is some webpacked website, You won't be able to do it with cheerio.

Comment: What data are you trying to get and on which page (I assume example.com isn't the actual URL)? Don't use cheerio with Puppeteer -- Puppeteer already has dynamic selectors so there's no need to re-parse the HTML and scrape it with an entirely separate static HTML parsing tool, unless the data is static, in which case you can drop Puppeteer. If you need to use Cheerio, please explain why -- what's your use case/context exactly?

Answer (score 0):

If it's not mandatory to use cheerio, I can suggest you a different method.

Requirements:

Two packages: [website-scraper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/website-scraper) and [website-scraper-puppeteer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/website-scraper-puppeteer)

Code:

```
const path = require('path');
const scrape = require('website-scraper');
const PuppeteerPlugin = require('website-scraper-puppeteer');

let url = ["https://pagetoscrap.com"]

let downloadPath = `/myFolder`;

await scrape({
    // Provide the URL of the website that you we want to fetch
    urls: url,
    // Specify the path where the content should be saved
    directory: path.resolve(__dirname, downloadPath),
    // Load the Puppeteer plugin
    plugins: [
        new PuppeteerPlugin({
            launchOptions: {
                // If you set  this to true, the headless browser will show up on screen
                headless: true,
                args: ['--no-sandbox', '--incognito']
            },
            scrollToBottom: {
                timeout: 10000,
                viewportN: 10
            },
            // Prevent page navigation
            blockNavigation: false,
        })
    ]
});
```

That's it. You can find the scraped data in `myFolder` folder

Comment: Thanks for your help.
Just I need to use Cheerio.